# How to pass environment variables to bash on different machine

Tags: bash

I need to run a shell script on a different machine. The general invocation method is like this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null bot-bono@other-dt 'bash' < $GIT_ROOT/chip/sw/scripts/build.sh
```

Due to other scripts being called by `build.sh` I can't pass parameters to it. AS far as I know if a `bash` is called locally it inherits the environment variables. That doesn't happen if it is called on a remote machine.

Done anyone know a way I can pass an environment variable to bash on a remote box? Or, perhaps there is a better way to invoke `build.sh` on a remote system that can use the local environment variables.

Comment: If you can't edit the actual `build.sh` you should be able to make a wrapper script that will take your environment variables as arguments, export them in the wrapper script and then just call build.sh from that subshell.

Comment: Or just simply when I think about it, depending on how you choose to do it, you should be able to just `export VAR=$VAR; export OTHERVAR=$OTHERVAR ... ; build.sh` as command to send to remote host. The environment variables set will _only_ be valid for that subshell still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use `-o SendEnv=YOURVARIABLE`, but it only works if the server is set to leniently allow variables. If it's not, here are possible workarounds:

You can set the variables in the command itself:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null bot-bono@other-dt \
    "export CFLAGS='$CFLAGS' LDFLAGS='$LDFLAGS'; bash" < $GIT_ROOT/chip/sw/scripts/build.sh
```

This does not require any specific SSH permissions, but it does require escaping the variables if they could contain single quotes.

If you have a lot of variables and don't want to sort through them, you can dump entire environment along with your script:

```
{ set; cat "$GIT_ROOT/chip/sw/scripts/build.sh" } | \
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null bot-bono@other-dt 'bash'
```

This sets all your local variables and functions on the remote system, but could cause issues since it doesn't limit it to the variables you want, and overrides variables like PATH and DISPLAY.